# Failing at passing a host name variable to a role

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-2.x

I am trying to pass two variables that contain host names to a role. Those host names will be user as hosts: values.

I tried like this.

```
 - hosts: host1,host2
   roles:
     - role: role1
       oldhost: host1
       newhost: host2
```

And like this.

```
- hosts: host1,host2
  tasks:
        - name: Transfering tar files.
          include_role:
            name: role1
          vars:
            oldhost: host1
            newhost: host2
```

But no matter what I do, I get the following error:

```
ERROR! unexpected parameter type in action: <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleSequence'>

The error appears to be in '/etc/ansible/custom/1943Asco/app/roles/userdata/tasks/main.yml': line 2, 
column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
- hosts: "{{oldhost | default('Invalid old host') }}"
  ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

with_items:
  - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

with_items:
  - "{{ foo }}"
```

This is my main.yml. I have a second one just after this one for host2.

```
---
- hosts: "{{ oldhost| default('Invalid host1') }}"
  vars:
    first: "$HOME/first.tar.gz"
    second: "$HOME/second.tar.gz"
    third: "$HOME/third.tar.gz"
    fourth: "$HOME/fourth.tar.gz"
  tasks:
        - name: Copy file from remote node onto local server.
          fetch:
            src: "{{item}}"
            dest: "/path/to/item/"
            flat: yes
            fail_on_missing: no
          with_items:
            - "{{first}}"
            - "{{second}}"
            - "{{third}}"
            - "{{fourth}}"


        - name: Delete the tar file
          local_action: file path="{{item}}" state=absent
          with_items:
            - "{{first}}"
            - "{{second}}"
            - "{{third}}"
            - "{{fourth}}"
```

Can anyone help me with this?

**EDIT**

I think the problem is coming from the fact that I can have only tasks in the main.yml file. And I have been passing 2 plays.

Comment: `tasks/main.yml` cannot include a host list.  A host list is for a play, and `tasks/main.yml` can only include tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by splitting the main.yml file into two roles. Now I am calling it like this and it works.

```
- hosts: host1
  tasks:
        - name: Section 1
          include_role:
            name: role1

- hosts: host2
  tasks:
        - name: Section 2
          include_role:
            name: role2
```